# Finding a common letter between two words, Can't find what's the bug in my code

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm supposed to write a code which gets two strings as an input and outputs True if there is a common letter and false if there isn't, I'm supposed to do this using recursion.

Running examples:

```
any_char_present("adsf","") #returns False
any_char_present("a","sfgserta") #returns true
```

My code gives me a correct answer for most cases, but for this case it gave me the wrong answer:

```
>>> any_char_present("abcefghijklmno","pqrstuvwxyza")
False
```

I can't figure out what's the bug in my code, here it is:

```
def any_char_present(s1,s2):
    if not s1 or not s2:
        return False
    if s1[0]==s2[0]:
        return True
    elif s1[0]!=s2[0]:
        s1=s1[1:]
        return any_char_present(s1,s2) or any_char_present(s2,s1)
```

Comment: you always only compare the first index ?  if s1[0]==s2[0]

Comment: print any_char_present("a","sfgserta") ---> This returns False

Answer (score 2):

This is because in your code, at the end of the first call, you are setting `s1` to be: `'bcefghijklmno'` and any comparisons made after that point will be different therefore it gives you `False`.

If this is a programming exercise, I will let you figure out the solution for yourself since that is probably why you are doing this exercise in the first place.

Other wise, you can do it as:

```
def any_char_present(s1, s2):
    return len(list(set(s1) & set(s2))) > 0
```

This will create a list of letters that are present in both strings and will then return `True` if the length of that list is greater than 0, i.e. there is atleast one common letter and `False` otherwise.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any built-in python functions, I'm supposed to do it using recursion only. I understand that my code compares only the first letter of s1 to every letter in s2, but I can't figure out how to compare the second and the third letter of s1 to s2

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that's homework so I will only guide you in the right direction.
Before that, just a thought: your code is not very efficient as you will test several times the same "subwords" to be convince, use a `print s1,s2` before the first if:

```
>>> any_char_present("abc","def")
abc def
bc def
c def
 def
def
def c
ef c   
f c    #this
 c
c
c f    #is here
 f
f
c ef
 ef
ef
def bc
ef bc
f bc
 bc
bc
bc f
c f   #is here again
 f
f
f c   #and here 
 c
c
bc ef
c ef    
 ef
ef
ef c    
f c  #and also there
 c
c
c f #or there
 f
f
```

Now, for your problem:
during the first iteration, you check `s1[0]` with `s2[0`], if they are different, you try to check the `rest of s1` with `s2`. But you haven't check `s1[0]` with the `rest of s2` yet.

So if the first letter of `s1` isn't the first letter of `s2`, but is the second letter of `s2`, your code will fail.

PS: if your homework isn't about recursion, check the `in` operator:

```
>>> 'c' in 'abcd'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a better and efficient solution as follows

```
def any_char_present(s1,s2):
  list1 = list(s1)  
  list2 = list(s2)  
  return set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

The last statement would return a list of chars which are common to both strings.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any built-in python functions, I'm supposed to do it using recursion only. 
I understand that my code compares only the first letter of s1 to every letter in s2, but I can't figure out how to compare the second and the third letter of s1 to s2